# PHP set array with variable

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make an array with a variable which has some array values. The problem is I am trying to add dynamic value in an array which has a fixed format. Here is my code:

```
$array_value="'id','name'";    
$aColumns = array( $array_value );
```

But it's not working. So array should be like(expected):

```
$aColumns = array( 'id','name' );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `$array_value` always has this sting format ?

Comment: You can achieve this using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. For instance: `explode(',', 'id,name')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `explode` to convert your string to an array and `str_replace` for replacing the apostrophes.

```
$aColumns = explode(',', str_replace('\'', '', $array_value));
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems like, you are going wrong with the format and expected declarations.

`$array_value` holds the value, which means you have assigned a value to the variable, and this holds `"'id','name'"` value completely.

if you think you require an array using a string, than you go with use of `explode()` expects two parameters,

1. a needle, here in your case it is `,`
2. the string to be exploded, in your case it is `'id','name'`